# Ubuntu won't let me login after software update

Tags: login, update-manager, lightdm

I'm a Ubuntu Newbie so I'll try to do my best but I'll need *step by step* procedures please.

I have 13.10 installed and after last night's update, I can't login. The keyboard is slow to answer and when I type in my password and press enter, the white dots in the background disappear as it always does when it logins but it doesn't, it just stays there...

Same happens with the guest account. I can't seem to open the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and when I go into Ubuntu Trusty Tahr it doesn't recognize my login.

I aslo can't go on Recovery mode by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> when I turn on the computer....

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem : reinstall Ubuntu by holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> down pushing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd>. Next, type in your `user` and `password` at tty6, and then type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

and that should do it.

Comment: Just to be clear, that should be `sudo` since linux is case sensitive ;)

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the SHIFT key ? And it also should be `ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: tty says my login is incorrect but it's not.

Comment: I found out I've been trying to log in the tty in the wrong way. It tried on my working computer with ubuntu and when I type in my account username it still says login incorrect so I guess I'm doing something wrong. What is your login for tty supposed to be??

Answer (score 0):

I eneded up reinstalling Ubuntu booting it from the cd beacause of frustration levels getting too high and I also needed the pc for work...It seems to be working fine now. Thank you anyway for your help

Answer (score 0):

When I had that problem I checked my .profile file and found that I had a unending statement, so just fixed the file. Of course I did it from tty, and when you try to log in, the system will try to run .profile or .bashrc. tty will log you in, but it will give you an error message, just read that message. If it doesn't give any message, then there might be something wrong with your display manager(gdm). So go into tty and install gdm, it will prompt you to pick your deafault(pick gdm).